# Enabling push notifications on PWA react app

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I need to enable push notifications on my PWA (progressive web app) react app. I need to send notifications to the user even when the user is not using the app like a notification on the phone. Is it possible if yes what service can i use to achieve this. On the front end i am using React and back end uses Dot net.